# Global disk resource becomes unavailable

Tags: python, linux, fileserver, flock

If I've got a global disk resource (mount point on an isilon file server) that multiple servers use to access a lock file. What is a good way to handle the situation if that global disk becomes unavailable and the servers can't access the global lock file?
Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1):

If this happens intermittently, you might just want to try waiting a short period and retrying.  Other than that... log the error and fail.  Maybe throw an exception that someone higher up can catch and deal with more gracefully.